# Rounded corners in IE 7+ with/without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

To create rounded corners on my container elements I use this CSS:

```
border-radius:12px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
```

However, IE does not appear to recognize and interpret the border-radius property (at least version 7-8, apparently its slated for version 9).

Is there a workaround for this that's doable entirely in CSS (no script, no extra markup)?

For JavaScript/jQuery solutions: I'd use a solution based on these if I could include a single script that would read my CSS, interpret the border-radius properties (**including border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius)**, and apply the corners accordingly. Does this exist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know for IE<9 there is no way to do this in pure CSS.

It has been documented that IE9 has border radius support.

There are [Javascript workarounds](http://davidwalsh.name/rounded-corners-ie) [available](http://www.curvycorners.net/), but as you said you don't want to implement them, you're a bit stuck.

Unless you want to use images, this works well if you have static size elements, but doesn't work if they change size.

Other than that, I am not aware of any pure CSS solution without a lot of hacky markup.

---

**Update**:

I already linked to a resource that can do this for you, the [CurvyCorners](http://www.curvycorners.net/) jQuery will detect the use of `-webkit-border-radius` and `moz-border-radius` on DOM elements and  duplicate the effect in IE using a series of small DIVs with no images. You can also tell it to apply the effect to specific elements.

---

**Update #2**:

After Spudley's suggestion of checking out [CSS3Pi](http://css3pie.com/)e, I would very much suggest this as the way to go as it uses the CSS property `behaviour` which only applies to IE, so it won't screw with the rest of the browsers, also this means no hacky markup added to your page (Curvy Corners adds many small divs) and no use of images.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, to encourage discussion, I've amended my question to include javascript/jQuery based solutions that meet the criteria of interpreting the css border-radius and doing the work the browser can't.

Comment: Updated with a link to a resource you may find helpful.

Comment: Ooops, I missed your update, anyway +1 and I´ll leave my answer as it´s linked to the current version...

Comment: scripts that add a "series of small divs" are a bad solution because they have issues with jagged edges and poor support for background images. Better to use a vector graphics solution like CSS3Pie.

Comment: I actually haven't seen CSS3Pie yet, but thanks for the heads up, I shall go check that out right now. :)

Comment: Kyle, I really, really like your suggested solution with one caveat. It does not support the use of conditional corners (ex: applying corners to the top left and top right only). Do you know if there's a version of curvy corners that recognizes and interprets -moz-border-radius-topright for example?

Comment: @Scott B: I believe Curvy Corners can do this, there is an "Instructions" link to the right, it explains how to use this function there.

Comment: @Kyle, thanks, I'll keep searching. As of now I can't find any "special" instructions for enabling support for anything other than all 4 corners. I really like this solution over the htc based css3Pie one because it works without me having to alter my css files. It just works retroactively. To make Pie work, I'll have to edit all my css files to add the htc behaviour.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. For CurvyCorners, as far as I saw, it takes the -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3ex; and does the work for you?

Comment: @Kyle: not exactly, according to my experience, and to the js file itself, it only appear to support two properties as of version 2.x > -webkit-border-radius, -moz-border-radius. Still looks to be a terrific solution if you don't need conditional corner support.

Comment: Update: I'm a bit unsure now. Perhaps it DOES support conditional corners, but just not the way I'm implementing them in my css. For example, I see this tab example, which does use conditional corners > http://www.curvycorners.net/includes/examples/demo5.html (just not sure yet how to feed it css to get it to understand border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius)

Comment: Best answer given all the requirements. Still working on conditional corner declarations though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You ask for a way to do it without scripting and without any extra markup. This simply isn't possible. The feature is missing from IE7/8, and the only way to get IE to do it is by simulating the feature either with scripting or markup.

The best options are ones which only affect IE and are invisible to other browsers. This means that [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com) stands head and shoulders above all the other options, because the technique it uses is only supported by IE. It also allows you to specify your border radius in CSS in the same way as for other browsers, making it more consistent.

Personally, I'd go for this solution every time. It's by far the cleanest solution you'll find for IE. Forget about any jQuery or pure javascript solutions; they almost all have issues of one sort or another, and as for markup options that involve corner graphics; just don't even think about it!

The real benefit that CSS3Pie has over other common solutions is that it uses a vector-graphics based solution, rather than pasting loads of divs into your document as CurvyCorners and others do. This means that the rounded corners CSS3Pie generates are smoothly drawn and works properly with background graphics on both the element itself and those behind it. Most other solutions have serious issues in these areas.

I don't know why you'd object to using scripting - especially HTC-based ones like this which don't get in the way of the other scripts. The absolute worst case is that a user has scripting turned off. And in that case, all they get is square corners; it's not the end of the world.

Comment: Thanks Spudley, I was close to using curvy corners as its very clean to  implement a single add on script that interprets the css and automatigically renders the corners, however, it does not appear to be applying my border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius settings. Do you know if CSS3Pie supports these off hand? I'm about to check it out.

Comment: @Scott B - CSS3Pie does support individual corners, but only using the combined `border-radius: a b c d;` syntax, rather than `-top-left-` etc. See the CSS3Pie documentation for more on that and his justification for why he did it that way.

Comment: CSS3Pie looks very impressive and it worked great in my testing, but it has one huge flaw (at least for my implementation) in that the path to the HTC file must be absolute. This is for a WordPress theme and I can't know in advance what that path will be before I distribute my theme to end users. Other than that I really like it.

Comment: @Scott B - There's a number of topics on the CSS3Pie forum around this issue. See this one which seems to have a solution: http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=8

Answer (score 2):

you can use .htc for border radius. 
[link1 for htc files](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser)  
[link2 for htc files](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fcurved-corner%2Fdownloads%2Fdetail%3Fname%3Dborder-radius.htc&rct=j&q=border-radius.htc&ei=YXILTaWyGom08QPOqI3KDQ&usg=AFQjCNEyt-MI57U5bJ2jtOdalVwbDQ-Vvw&cad=rja)

I suggest to have a look at this site. 
 [CSS3 Please](http://www.css3please.com)

Answer (score 1):

The scripting / jQuery solution you are talking about does exist, take a look at [jQuery Curvy Corners](http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/).